# Multiple Kinects: Same Topics from different nodes, how to subscribe?

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

If anyone has any links or references about connecting 2 or more Kinects to the same computer and specifically obtaining & integrating data from them, could you please reply here?
So I am able to launch separate files for each kinect and am able to launch data separately. Here's the output of my rxgraph
[image: image description]

The problem is my process listens to a topic and it cannot distinguish between same topics from different nodes, **how can I make them publish topics with unique names? or how can I listen to topics from a specific node?**

Best,

CV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9356/multiple-kinects:-same-topics-from-different-nodes,-how-to-subscribe?/) by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 284 on 2011-03-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-09**:
@tfoote: I've edited the question, thank you.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-09**:
Could you specify what you mean by multiple kinects?  Do you want data on connecting multple kinects on one computer or are you talking data fusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The new drivers used by [openni_kinect](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect) support multiple cameras on one computer.

For fusing data I suggest looking [PCL](http://ros.org/wiki/pcl)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-09**:
thanks tfoote, I'll try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To make each instance publish on a different topic use [topic remapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments)  Also there is [roslaunch syntax for remapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-09**:
awesome, this is what I was looking for. Anyways, even after remapping am not able to visualize both kinects using RVIZ.